# Python - How would I get the strength of a magnetic field at a given point in space in blender?

Tags: python, force-fields

I am really new to blender, but I know that you can create magnetic fields, so is there a method built into the blender python module which gives you the magnetic field strength at any given point in space? What I want to do is that I want to add arrows (vectors) to each point in space indicating the field strength, so to do that I'd get the field strength at one point, and then loop across a grid of points around the magnetic field, and at each point I'd add an arrow mesh with the length proportional to the strength and it will point in the direction of the field.

Then I want to animate this setup so that the vectors are constantly refreshing so that when I move the magnetic field object, so do the vectors in proportion. Is that possible?

3Blue1Brown has made 2D Electric and magnetic field illustrations in [this](https://youtu.be/MzRCDLre1b4?t=1m46s) video. I want to do something like that. And I'm sorry if this is a "Do my work for me question". I'm just beginning with Blender. And thanks for all the help in advance :)

---

TL;DR:

I want a python method from `bpy` which gives me the strength of a magnetic field at a given point in space mainly.